# Form-based HTTP digest authentication

Tags: javascript, browser, digest-authentication

I'm about to embark on POC using Javascript to simulate the digest authentication steps between client and server. I'm ok on an individual request but what about requests during the entire session.

Specifically, I'm wondering how the browser would handle subsequent requests once the login is successful. Is the browser clever enough to remember the necessary headers used during the login exchange, even though this occurred in Javascript, so that it can continue to use the same nonce and increment the nc as appropriate.

Comment: You would probably want to implement the digest auth in the server side. Client side can be easily modified and it's insecure to use it to verify authentication data. Is there any specific reason you'd want to avoid sending requests to the server? They can be "inline" without reloading the page if you use AJAX to do so

Comment: @ianbeks did this work?

Comment: @casraf
I think you misunderstood, he wants to submit using js or ajax, but was wondering if the browser would cache those credentials afterward, once a successful Authorization header was returned.

Answer (score 0):

If Digest Auth is not a hard requirement I would suggest using a Token Authentication strategy, it works well for browser apps.  If you are writing a "single page app" that is going to talk to an API, you can read this article of mine for more information: [Token Based Authentication for Single Page Apps (SPAs)](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa/)